# Change the text of checkbox on changing state of radio button

Tags: asp.net

I have asp.net webpage on which i have radio button as well as check boxes.
I need to change the text of check box when there will be any change in radio buttons state.

Please suggest how can i achieve that...

I tried with the event of radio button's state changed event & on that i have set the text property of Check box.
This i have done in background .cs file
but it is not happening.

Please suggest.
Thank

Answer (score 1):

You need to set RadioButton's property `AutoPostBack=true` and handler `CheckedChanged` event.

Example:

```
<asp:RadioButton 
              ID="RadioButton1" 
              runat="server" 
              AutoPostBack="True" 
              GroupName="Group1" 
              oncheckedchanged="RadioButton1_CheckedChanged" />
 <asp:RadioButton 
              ID="RadioButton2" 
              runat="server" 
              AutoPostBack="True" 
              GroupName="Group1" 
              oncheckedchanged="RadioButton1_CheckedChanged" />
 <asp:CheckBox ID="CheckBox1" runat="server" />
```

And code behind:

```
 protected void RadioButton1_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        CheckBox1.Text = RadioButton1.Checked ? "Checked" : "Not Checked";
    }
```

Comment: Hey AVD! Nice answer but Vijay wants to change the text of a checkbox not a radiobutton.

Answer (score 1):

You can set AutoPostBack property to true. This adds JavaScript to client which automatically rises postback event.

**aspx**

```
<asp:RadioButton ID="RadioButton1" runat="server" AutoPostBack="True" 
       oncheckedchanged="RadioButton1_CheckedChanged" />
<asp:CheckBox ID="CheckBox1" runat="server" />
```

**.cs**

```
protected void RadioButton1_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    CheckBox1.Text = "some text...";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

From the information you have provided I would recommend using `Javascript` to accomplish this as it would greatly improve the user experience. If you could provide more details I could give you more information.

**Edit as per your comments**

The markup:

```
<asp:RadioButtonList ID="RadioButtonList1" runat="server">
    <asp:ListItem Value="RadioButton1">RadioButton1</asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem Value="RadioButton2">RadioButton2</asp:ListItem>
</asp:RadioButtonList>

<asp:CheckBox ID="Checkbox1" runat="server" Text="RadioButton1" />
```

The javascript:

```
$(function () {
    $("#<%=RadioButtonList1.ClientID %> input:radio").change(function () {
        $("#<%=Checkbox1.ClientID %>").next().text($("#<%=RadioButtonList1.ClientID %> input:radio:checked").val());
    });
});
```

The `RadioButtonList` will generate a `<Table>` in HTML with the `ID` of `RadioButtonList1`. The javascript selector selects all radio buttons from within that table. Though this will satisfy what you are asking for, POSTing to the server is another thing.

Comment: As i told, i have checkbox say "Checkbox1" having text="Text1". I also have Radiobutton say "Radio1" & "Radio2". Now by default Radio1 is checked. But when i check the Radio2 then the text of Checkbox1 should change to "Text2".  This is what i want but honestly I'm new to ASP.net as well as JavaScript... Please help

Answer (score -1):

I think by using jquery for achieving the task will increase peformance by preventing postback.

```
    <script> 
        $(function() { 
            $("input[name='<%=RadioButton1.ClientID %>']").change(function(){
            $("#<%= CheckBox1.ClientID%>").next("label:first").text("New Text"); 
            });
        });  
    </script>
```

assuming the radio button has ID "RadioButton1", checkbox as ID "CheckBox1".

Comment: -1 the first selector that you have there will only grab all elements of type `RadioButton1.ClientID` so if the ClientID was 'test' then it would grab all like `<test />`. The second selector will not display text for a radio button as there is no text property of a radio button.

Comment: Really not trying to give you here but...you've got a typo when using an id selector you are missing the `#` sign. Also, since radio buttons are a collection, setting the id property is not appropriate...instead you should use the name property and change your selector to something like `input[name='<%=RadioButton1.ClientID %>']`. There should only ever be one ocurance of an id within a page on top of that if you use the `#` sign to indicate to jQuery that you want an element with a specified `id`, it will only ever return 0 or 1 items.